# capability of redis in handling 'N' no of connections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, redis

if there are any performance measurements with Redis in terms
of how many simultaneous subscriptions/channels it can handle?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a benchmark of this, but the complexity of pushing to subscribed channels is in the O(N) family.
from the docs:

PUBLISH:

```
O(N+M) where N is the number of clients subscribed to the
receiving channel and M is the total number of subscribed 
patterns (by any client).
```

PSUBSCRIBE (subscribe to patterns):

```
O(N) where N is the number of patterns the client is already subscribed to.
```

SUBSCRIBE:

```
O(N) where N is the number of channels to subscribe to.
```